# gitlab for loop failed

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have a job for my pipeline

```
deploy-test:
  stage: test
  only:
    - /^B[Ii]-.*$/
  script:
     - > 
       pbifiles=$(git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1 -- '***.pbix')
       for pbifile in pbifiles
       do
          echo "Publishin $pbifile to BI-Test...."
          python UploadPBITest.py --files $pbifile
       done
```

but everytime i get this error:

> $ pbifiles=$(git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1 -- '***.pbix') for
> pbifile in pbifiles; do echo "Publishin $pbifile to BI-Test...."
> python UploadPBITest.py --files $pbifile done
> /bin/sh: eval: line 142: syntax error: unexpected "do"
> Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
> 00:00
> ERROR: Job failed: exit code 2

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can notice: Wouldnt you need to iterate over the **content** of pbifiles? Like so:

```
for pbifile in $pbifiles
```